# Regex to match all scala keywords in a file

Tags: regex, scala

Is it possible to build a regexp to match all keywords in a scala source file?

The best I came with so far:

```
"""(?<![\w`])(%s)(?![\w\_])""" format keyword
```

Is this good enough or I missed something?

Comment: This would match one keyword, not all, wouldn't it?

Comment: @userunknown - I meant all keywords one-by-one, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious solution is to build a regexp for matching all keywords, and you can do that by simply creating a big OR-ing of keywords `(if|else|...)`. However, you'll need to exclude strings, comment and any text which may contain free keywords that aren't keywords.

When we think about regular expressions there are limits to what can be accomplished by regexp in a practical manner. That's to say that, regexp is not necessarily a good fit for your problem.

The reason for this is that you have to match a lot of invalid input and then discard it.

> e.g. how will you handle typical C-style comments that terminate on a
>   new line?

Ultimately, what you need is a tokenizer for Scala, and you could probably find that in the Scala distribution.

Comment: I just thought that building this with the help of scala compiler is a bit of overkill.

Comment: I bet you can get it to work, just saying, that if you dig into Scala, you're bound to find a tokenizer class that you can invoke yourself, and it's gonna do this for you and it will be correct. And in the future you'll know about these classes and how you can use them to empower your projects.

Comment: I already dug into scala compiler already, and was using its AST's to do highlighting work, and I just wanted to simplify the job by replacing all keywords by regexp. Since there are strings and comments and so on, it seems I'll need to do it with the compiler.